# Reading XML attribute value based on another attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to retrevie a error message based on the errorcode i pass.How can i do that using linq?

Here is my xml document layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<errors>
  <error code="101" message="Our Database is currently experience problems!">   
  </error>
</errors>
```

here is my load code in C#

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/ErrorCodes.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could load the document once, turning it into a `Dictionary<int, string>` like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/ErrorCodes.xml"));
var errors = doc.Root.Elements("error")
                .ToDictionary(x => (int) x.Attribute("code"),
                              x => (string) x.Attribute("message"));
```

(You could do this on web-app load.)

Or if you really just need to find a single message:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/ErrorCodes.xml"));
var errors = doc.Root.Elements("error")
                .Where(x => (int) x.Attribute("code") == code)
                .Single()
                .Attribute("message").Value;
```

Note that `XDocument` is part of LINQ to XML; `XmlDocument` isn't.